# Grails Atmosphere missed connection

Tags: grails, atmosphere

I've used [the sample](https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-atmosphere-meteor-sample) to check how atmosphere works and a little modified it: add a service to send messages:

```
def sendMessage(String message){
        String mapping = "/jabber/chat/12345"
        Broadcaster b = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(DefaultBroadcaster.class, mapping)
        println("Broadcast resources size:" +b.getAtmosphereResources().size())
        def resp = [type: "chat", resource: mapping, message: message] as JSON
        b.broadcast(resp)
    }
```

But looks like when I call the function some times AtmosphereResource for my connection in broadcaster is missed and client didn't recieve a message. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging switched to **SimpleBroadcaster** implementation and now code works pretty fine:
Handler class

```
@Override
    void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String mapping = "/jabber/chat" + request.getPathInfo()
        Broadcaster b = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(SimpleBroadcaster.class, mapping, true)
        Meteor m = Meteor.build(request)
        m.setBroadcaster(b)
    }
```

Service

```
def sendMessage(String message){
        String mapping = "/jabber/chat/12345"
        Broadcaster b = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(mapping)
        println("Broadcast resources size:" +b.getAtmosphereResources().size())
        def resp = [type: "chat", resource: mapping, message: message] as JSON
        b.broadcast(resp)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all what transport protocol you are using ?

If it is 'long-polling'(default) or 'polling' atmosphere try to reconnect after 5 minutes(default)  if no message (or event) are sent or received.

Maybe one of reconnections is field ?

I have some similar issue system was reconnecting only 5 times. So after 5x5minutes no connection was between client and server.
Check browser log/established connections to see do your browser have valid connection to server. 
Also try to play with atmosphere [props](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/jQuery.atmosphere.js-atmosphere.js-API) (reduce value of **timeout** conf to 10000 and try to reproduce problem.)